# Why is there a chgrp command if there is chown

Tags: chown

After working 15 years with Linux, I stumbled upon the command `chgrp`. Until now, I always used `chown` to change the ownership of a file, even if I only changed the group; for example

```
chown :www-data index.php
```

So I wonder if there is anything that `chgrp` can do what `chown` cannot do. IMHO, the man pages do not point to specific advantage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your example:

```
chown :group file
```

does not work (it may work on some platforms but is non standard). It usually at the same time changes the owner of the file.

Also note that the colon method in chown has been added approx. 25 years ago, while `chgrp` is much older.

Comment: Since it does not work that way on POSIX, it should not be mentioned, unless you like to create vendor lock ins.

Comment: Since it is questionable what should be done in these corner cases, it is unlikely to be standardized. Using features that may create random results on various platforms is not a good idea, in special since there is a better and documented way.

Comment: As long as people mention that something may cause problems I have no problems. BTW: as an example... I've seen many people advertizing that GNU tar supports incremental backups. Unfortunately these people do not mention that is does not support incremental restores (except for simple cases). Maybe you understand why I try to warn people on things that might cause problems.

Comment: Oh I definitely understand, and I appreciate it; thanks for editing your answer!